# How to create a method to add and multiple in a circular increment?

Tags: java, types, increment

For instance, whenever my count is equal to 4294967295 + 1 I want that the count restart from 0.
Basically I`m trying to simulate a unsigned 32 bits in java that has range [0, 4294967295]. The methods that I'm trying to create is ADD and MULTIPLE.

For example, if I have the number 4294967295 and I multiple by 2, I will get the result 4294967294.

Since Java does not have a unsigned int, I need to create that class to "simulate" the C int uint32_t in Java.

If I multiple 1103527590 * 1103515245 the result should be 4294967294, but my code is giving the result 2524872877

```
public class Unsigned32BitsInt {

    private long limit; // Upper bound 4294967295

    public Unsigned32BitsInt(long limit) {
        this.limit = limit;
    }

    public long add(long x, long y) {

        long result = 0L;

        if (x + y < this.limit) {

            if ((x + y) % this.limit == 0) {
                result = (x + y) / 2;
            } else {
                result = (x + y) % this.limit;
            }

        } else {

            if ((x + y) % this.limit == 0) {
                result = (x + y) / (Math.max(x, y) / Math.min(x, y)) - 1;
            } else {
                result = (x + y) % this.limit - 1;
            }

        }

        return result;
    }
    

    public long multiple(long x, long y) {
        long result = 1L;

        long r = x*y;
        long c = result = (x * y) % this.limit;
        
        
        if (x * y < this.limit) {

            if ((x * y) % this.limit == 0) {
                result = (x + y) / 2;
            } else {
                result = (x * y) % this.limit;
            }
            
        } else {
            
            if ((x * y) % this.limit == 0) {
                result = (x * y) / 2 - 1;
            } else {
                result = (x * y) % this.limit - 1;
            }
        }

        return result;
    }

}
```

Comment: "*How* is but the form following the function of "*Why*". So why do you need to simulate an unsigned 32-bit integer in Java?

Comment: What is the problem with the posted code? How have you tested it?  What tests fail?

Comment: I added one of the cases that the program fails

Comment: _"1103527590 * 1103515245 the result should be 4294967294"_ - Why that? `#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

int main(void) {
  uint32_t a = 1103527590;
  uint32_t b = 1103515245;
  uint32_t c = a * b;
  printf("%" PRIu32 "\n", c);
  return 0;
}` is giving me `2524872878`? My scala REPL is giving me `2524872878` as well.

Comment: *If I multiple 1103527590 * 1103515245 the result should be 4294967294, but my code is giving the result 2524872877*   Well, If I multiply it or simply to iterative adding I get `2524872878.`

Comment: You want `(x*y) % (limit+1)`, i.e. `0x100000000` or just `(x*y) & limit`. I don't understand your `- 1`s or `/ 2` at all -- can you explain what they are for?

Comment: Do the "unsigned" methods in the ['Integer` API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html) help?

Comment: "If I multiple 1103527590 * 1103515245 the result should be 4294967294" If I use an online large  number calculator, I also get `2,524,872,878`

Answer (score 2):

Int's are only signed from the standpoint of comparisons and display.  Internally signed and unsigned are no different.

So when the count is `4294967295` that is `-1` in twos complement form.  So you add `1` and you get `0` as required. You can print it unsigned by casting it to a long like so.

```
int s = -1;
// prints 4294967295
System.out.println(((long)s)&0xffff_ffffL);
```

If count is `Integer.MAX_VALUE` you have `count = 2147483647` you can add `1` and get `2147483648`.  You can cast it to a long to print it as unsigned instead of the normal `-2147483648`.

To do general comparisons, use the built-in method
`Integer.unsignedCompare(int x, int y);`
to compare two integers as `32` bit unsigned values.

And finally,

```
int a = 1_103_527_590;
int b = 1_103_515_245;
System.out.println((long)(a*b) & 0xffff_ffffL);
```

prints

```
2524872878
```

**Update**

As pointed out by [Andrey Tyukin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2707792/andrey-tyukin) instead of the casting to `long` and `masking` of the value, the `Integer` class method `Integer.toUnsignedString()` can be used to print the unsigned value.  For more useful methods check out the [Integer](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Integer.html) class in the Java API.

Answer (score 1):

```
The answer from @WJS makes a good point:
```

> [Integers] are only signed from the standpoint of comparisons and display. Internally signed and unsigned are no different.

In Java, doing arithmetic on integer types does not result in overflow.[1]  The values wrap around. Along with `~unsigned` methods in some of the the APIs, such as the [`Integer` API](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Integer.html), this makes it easy to do unsigned arithmetic.

Even so, it might be convenient to have unsigned `class`es. Here is part of one for a 32-bit integer:

```
 public final class Unsigned32BitInt implements      
         Comparable<Unsigned32BitInt> {
    
    public static final Unsigned32BitInt ZERO = new 
         Unsigned32BitInt (0);
    public static final Unsigned32BitInt ONE = new 
         Unsigned32BitInt (1);
    
    private final int value; // [2]
    
    public Unsigned32BitInt () { value = 0; }
    public Unsigned32BitInt (long v) {  
        value = (int) v ;       
    }
    public Unsigned32BitInt (int v) {
        value = v;        
    }
    
    @Override
    public int compareTo (Unsigned32BitInt  other) {
        return Integer.compareUnsigned (this.value, other.value);
    }
    
    @Override
    public boolean equals (Object other) {
        if (this == other) return true;
        if (other == null) return false;
        if ( ! (other instanceof Unsigned32BitInt )) return false;
        return Integer.compareUnsigned 
           (this.value, ((Unsigned32BitInt) other).value) == 0;
    }
    
    @Override
    public int hashCode () { return value; }

    public Unsigned32BitInt add (Unsigned32BitInt i) {  // [3]
        return  new Unsigned32BitInt (i.value + this.value);      
    }               
            
    public Unsigned32BitInt multiply (Unsigned32BitInt i) {
        long a = i.value;
        long b = value;
        return new Unsigned32BitInt (a * b);
    }
    
    @Override
    public String toString () { 
        return Integer.toUnsignedString(value);
    }
 }
```

You can continue, adding methods, including overriden methods and overloaded methods, to fit your needs.

In some cases, as shown in `toString` and `compareTo` here, methods will be wrappers for methods in the `Byte`, `Short`, `Integer`, or `Long` APIs.

**NOTES:**

[1] If you need arithmetic that can throw an `ArithmeticException` on overflow, there are `~Exact` methods in the [`Math` API](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Math.html)

[2] I made Objects of type `Unsigned32BitInt` immutable. I kept the values as 32 bit integers.

[3] My preference would be to have the arithmetic operations be instance methods, e.g. `c = a.add(b);`, `sum = sum.add(a);`. From your example, you might prefer `static` methods. One such method might look like this:

```
 public static Unsigned32BitInt add 
    (Unsigned32BitInt a, Unsigned32BitInt b) {
        return new Unsigned32BitInt (a.value + b.value);
    }
```

Comment: I can copy-paste my comment on the other answer verbatim: "Why would one trust this bit-fiddling more than the official [`Integer.toUnsignedString`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html)-API? What's the point?" You're all trying to reinvent square wheels to solve a problem that doesn't exist.